# How can I retrieve objects from back4app using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, back4app

I am trying to interact with a database stored in back4app using python. After sending my GET request, I get "{'message': 'Not Found', 'error': {}}". My python code is as follows:

```
import json, http.client, urllib.parse
# create a connection to the server
url = "parseapi.back4app.com"
connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
connection.connect()

# define parameter for GET request
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({"Name": "Dru Love"})})

# perform GET request
connection.request('GET', '/parse/classes/PGA?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "app_id",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "api_key"
     })

# store response in result variable
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
connection.close()
print(result)
```

Response:

```
{'message': 'Not Found', 'error': {}}
```

Comment: Without *reading the docs* (pointer) I'm wondering about the `$`. It doesn't look right.

Comment: Before the rest api key? It's in the rest api docs provided by back4app. I tried removing it and nothing seems to change, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the call to connection.request(). The "/parse" should be removed from the url that gets passed in. The working code looks as follows:

```
connection.request('GET', '/classes/PGA?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": app_id,
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": api_key,
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really recommend to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) package. The package is very nice, for `HTTP` calls.

Little example for the your case.

```
# Your payloads
params = {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "app-id",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "YOUR_IP_KEY"
}


url = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/parse/classes/Congressmen'


# GET method, with URI parameters
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.url)

# Get json data from a response.
print(response.json())
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. The response I get is: {'error': 'unauthorized'}

Comment: `{'error': 'unauthorized'} ` meant that you provided an bad credentials, check your `app-id` or `api_key`.

Comment: My app-id and Rest-Api-key are definitely correct, I have quadruple checked them at this point. The thing I am most unsure about is honestly the url I am using. Am I using the correct url? If not, where do I find the correct one?

Comment: I don't know anything about `parseapi`

Answer (score 0):

To connect to back4app using python requests module, you need to define App ID and REST API Key in headers (not using params)

```
# Your payloads
headers = {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "app-id",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "YOUR_IP_KEY"
}


url = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/parse/classes/Congressmen'


# GET method, with URI parameters
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.url)

# Get json data from a response.
print(response.json())
```